# Is there non-English magic?

Tags: jonathan-strange-and-mr-norrell

The BBC miniseries *Jonathan Strange and Mr. Norrell* seems in large part to be concerned with the so-called revival or restoration of English magic, which departed England with the legendary Raven King, John Uskglass. With this being the case,  the plot focuses primarily on English magicians such as Strange and Norrell themselves. It seems to be suggested that the Raven King brought magic to England (perhaps from Faerie?), as the King’s prophecy says:

> I gave magic to England, a valuable inheritance.
>
> But Englishmen have
> despised my gift.

On the other hand, magic certainly *works* outside of England, as evidenced by Mr. Strange’s efforts in the Peninsula, or his summoning of the Gentleman in Venice. Further, the French army does not seem to be shocked by the appearance of magicians in the English army (though, with Strange’s accomplishments, they are undoubtedly dismayed).

So is there non-English magic?  Do any other countries have their own magic? Can magicians be born outside of England, to English parents or otherwise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think we know. It is never addressed in the book nor the series. I assume though that you can have non-English magic. 
First there is one obvious source of non-English magic: Faerie. English magic refers to magic done in England and seems to include both Norrel's non-faerie magic and Uskglass's magic which involved summoning faeries. The term English suggests there is a form of non-English magic to compare it with. This could be faerie but I find that unlikely given the close links between English and faerie magic. This suggests other countries may once have had magic. Since they don't use it in the book it is likely that, like English magic before Norrel, foreign magic has declined.

Comment: I don't recall if this was in the book, but in the show, there was some allusion as well that some or all magic is performed through alliances with natural elements and forces (alliance which Uskglass established in England). It could be that English magic refers to magic that's source is the allied forces within England, which would broadly account for both the commonality and diversities between national magics.